# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python

Пытаюсь вытащить с стайта ссылку на фотографию с помощью urllib. Ссылка получается с русскими символами, так как имя файла на русском. Вобщем в итоге вот что получаю:

> \xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81-\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5-\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b-\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb-103470

Толи это кодировка какая, или я чёт не то парсю)

Comment: Так все понятно же. \x говорит от том, что дальше шестнадцатеричный код символа, дальше два символа характеризующие код символа, очевидно кириллицы. Наверняка есть в Питоне штатный функционал декодирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print """\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81-\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5-\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b-\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb-103470""".decode('UTF-8')
```

> > Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Попал-103470

Answer (score 0):

В какой кодировке страница сайта, в такой же должна быть и ссылка.